# Text not being written to file

Tags: java, file

I cannot seem to figure this out. In the method below I'm trying to write a boolean to a file in 2 places, however nothing is actually being written. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void renameTables(){
    String path = MessengerMain.getInstance().getDataFolder() + File.separator + "v3-0-0 Table Rename.txt";
    File f = new File(path);
    try(ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%", null); Writer w = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, false))){
        if (!f.exists()){
            f.createNewFile();
            w.write("false");
            w.flush();
        }

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        if (lines.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            System.out.println("[Messenger] Verifying table names...");
            int count = 0;
            List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
            tables.add("messages");
            tables.add("scores");
            tables.add("contacts");
            while (rs.next()){
                String table = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                if (tables.contains(table)){
                    update("ALTER TABLE " + table + " RENAME TO " +  ("messenger_" + table) + ";");
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0){
                System.out.println("[Messenger] Done. " + count + " table" + (count == 1 ? "" : "s") + " renamed.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("[Messenger] Done. No tables need to be renamed.");
            }
            w.write("true");
            w.flush();
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Following Elliot Frisch's advice (same results):

```
private void renameTables(){
    String path = MessengerMain.getInstance().getDataFolder() + File.separator + "v3-0-0 Table Rename.txt";
    File f = new File(path);
    try(ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%", null)){
        Writer w = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, false));
        if (!f.exists()){
            f.createNewFile();
            w.write("false");
            w.close(); //close here
        }

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        if (lines.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            System.out.println("[Messenger] Verifying table names...");
            int count = 0;
            List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
            tables.add("messages");
            tables.add("scores");
            tables.add("contacts");
            while (rs.next()){
                String table = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                if (tables.contains(table)){
                    update("ALTER TABLE " + table + " RENAME TO " +  ("messenger_" + table) + ";");
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0){
                System.out.println("[Messenger] Done. " + count + " table" + (count == 1 ? "" : "s") + " renamed.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("[Messenger] Done. No tables need to be renamed.");
            }
            w = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, false)); //create a new writer
            w.write("true");
            w.close(); //close here
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? Are you sure those statements are being reached?

Comment: Consider: You are asking us to examine a significant amount of code to debug it by inspection, without providing something we can compile and run.  You on the other hand can run your program and step through it in a debugger and probably find the problem on your own.

Comment: Yes the file is being created and I'm getting an error where I try to read from the file because there's nothing in there

Comment: So what did debugging tell you? Or are you just ignoring everyones suggestion?

Comment: Once again, everything is being run, however when I get to the part where I read from the file it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException (something I'll fix later) because there's nothing in the file

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the only part, line 11

Comment: You've written and flushed, but you didn't close the file handle. That's why nothing has been written yet. The try-with-resources will close **after** you attempt to read.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Same results as before. I updated the post with what I did

Comment: Again, is that code being reached? Are you certain?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I am

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I stand corrected. In the block where I check if the file exists nothing gets run after createNewFile() for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working full [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "temp.txt");
    String path = f.getPath();
    try (Writer w = new FileWriter(f)) {
        w.write("false");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        System.out.println(lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output is (as expected)

```
[false]
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing though?

Comment: Minus everything we can't verify; I can only conclude that in your post(s) the statements are not being reached.